# SQL Function that returns dynamically pivotted data

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

Is it at all possible to have a table valued function in MSSQL that takes an attribute and generates an associated SQL statement with Pivot function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnPivot (@EntityTypeID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @COLS varchar(MAX);

    select @COLS=coalesce(@COLS+',','')+'['+Name+']'from c_EntityAttribute WHERE EntityTypeID = @EntityTypeID;

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT EntityInstanceID, AttributeName, Value FROM v_EntityElementData WHERE EntityTypeID = 1) as s';
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'PIVOT ( MIN(Value) FOR AttributeName IN (' + @COLS + ') ) AS p';

    RETURN EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL ;
END
```

Comment: I have managed to get the flexibility i wanted by building my views (using PIVOT) in a stored proc which can be scheduled to reproduce the views when necessary. Let me know if anyone wants the PROC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately not, with the exception of stored procedures SQL Server keeps track of the table definition of the output of all views, functions etc.  Thus the columns and types can't change dynamically on the input.

For this reason  I've never found the PIVOT operator to be useful.  Generally the only way to get varying column data out is to treat it as XML.

For what reason are you pivoting it?  This is usually a UI concern, and so I would recommend doing it at the UI, or SSRS etc.

Comment: The issue is that the System relies on an EAV data structure, but am trying to build a dynamic reporting layer that does not require too much maintenance. Will probably return to stored procs that generate the static tables based on the EAV meta. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I do similar and use the Matrix / Tablix functionality within SSRS to pivot it on render - works very neatly

Comment: I have to disagree that this is a UI concern. That is like saying that all data is a UI concern. The RDBS is best suited to slice and dice data. Otherwise, you have to send way more over the wire to the app layer just so the UI widget or some such can manipulate it. No way I want 50000 records on the wire so the UI can make a pivot view.

Answer (score 3):

A table valued function must always return a specified schema, so this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I did to accommodate this kind of feature (as a view, but a function would follow the same methodology). We stuck it at the end of every install script so when any changes were made to the table being pivoted, they would be picked up in the re-generated view.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM   sys.objects
       WHERE  object_id = Object_id(N'[dbo].[vwYourView]')
              AND type IN ( N'V' ))
BEGIN
  DROP VIEW [dbo].[vwYourView]
END
GO                            

Declare @cols VARCHAR(MAX)

Select @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + YourColumn+ ']',
                                 '[' + YourColumn+ ']')
                                 FROM YourTable
                                 Order By YourColumn

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
Set @query =
N'
Create View vwYourView
AS
Select * FROM YourTable
Pivot (
    MAX(YourVal)
    FOR YourColumn IN( '+
        @cols
    +')
) AS pvt
'

Execute(@query)

Select * FROM [vwYourView]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made the following procedure for dynamically pivoting all the values in a table.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.spDynamicPivot (
  @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)              --The query to pivot
, @AggregateFunction NVARCHAR(MAX)  --The aggregation function surrounding the column name to be pivoted
, @ValueColumn NVARCHAR(MAX)        --The value column from which to create columns
, @ResultTable NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL --An optional table name into which the results will be stored. Note, this unfortunately will not work with #temp tables.
) AS BEGIN

  SET XACT_ABORT ON;
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT @cols = ISNULL(@cols + '','', '''') + ''['' + Val + '']'' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Val = ' + @ValueColumn + ' FROM (' + @Query + ') a) b;';
  DECLARE @paramDef NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@cols NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramDef, @cols = @cols OUTPUT;

  DECLARE @resultSetSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = IIF(ISNULL(@ResultTable, '') <> '', 'INTO ' + @ResultTable + ' ', '');
  SET @sql = 'SELECT * ' + @resultSetSql + 'FROM (' + @Query + ') q PIVOT( ' + @AggregateFunction + ' FOR ' + @ValueColumn + ' IN (' + @cols + ') ) p';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

END
```

Usage:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
CREATE TABLE #t (Name VARCHAR(50), Age INT, NetWorth FLOAT);
INSERT INTO #t VALUES 
('Bill', 50, 250),
('Barb', 17, 15),
('Fred', 25, 30),
('Bill', 25, 100),
('Kahless', 90000, 4E10) 

--Displaying results directly
EXEC dbo.spDynamicPivot @Query = 'SELECT * FROM #t', @AggregateFunction = 'AVG(NetWorth)', @ValueColumn = 'Name'

--Or writing them into a table for additional use
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.MyTable;
EXEC dbo.spDynamicPivot @Query = 'SELECT * FROM #t', @AggregateFunction = 'AVG(NetWorth)', @ValueColumn = 'Name', @ResultTable = 'tempdb.dbo.MyTable'

SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.MyTable
```